# C++ Copy Constructor Need Help & Error Keeps Occurring. Error is request for 'ex' in 'ex', which is of non-class type 'int*'

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I'm a college student that's honestly struggling with Data Structures and I could use some help with my copy constructor. For this lab I am supposed to reverse an array, but I currently getting really stumped on the copy constructor, which is supposed to construct a new IntArray object and x taking in another IntArray.

This is what was presented to me and so far I managed to get the constructor and destructor down, but whenever I do the copy constructor I keep getting either error: request for member 'length' in 'other', which is of non-class type 'int*'or other random errors.

```
#ifndef __INT_ARRAY_H__
#define __INT_ARRAY_H__

namespace ds {

/**
 * @brief Array of integers
 */
class IntArray {
private:
  /**
   * @brief The internal array of integers
   */
  int *storedArray; 

public:
  /**
   * @brief Length of array
   */
  int length;

  /**
   * @brief Construct a new IntArray object
   *
   * @param len length of the IntArray
   */
  IntArray(int len) {
    // TODO: initialize data members

    storedArray = new int[len];
    length = len;

  }
```

Here is the copy constructor. I have been working on it so far, but I just cannot wrap my head around it. If anyone could help me solve this it would be much appreciated.

```
  /**
   * @brief Construct a new IntArray object
   *
   * @param x another IntArray object
   */
  IntArray(const IntArray &x) {
    // TODO: complete the copy constructor

    int *other;
    int arr[length];
    length = other.length;
    

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = x.storedArray[length];
    }
   
  }

  /**
   * @brief Destroy the IntArray object
   */
  ~IntArray() {
    // TODO: delete the internal array
    
    delete [] storedArray;

  }
```

This is the main.cpp if its any help

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "IntArray.h"
#include "catch.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

TEST_CASE("All") {
  // define an array of 10 ints
  ds::IntArray nums(10);

  // randomly add 10 ints to the array
  srand(time(0)); // setting the seed for rand()
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    nums[i] = rand() % 10 + 1; // generating random numbers by rand()
  }

  // print the array to a string stream
  std::stringstream originalSS;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    originalSS << nums[i] << " ";
  }

  // test the copy constructor
  SECTION("Copy") {
    // make a copy
    ds::IntArray copyArr(nums);
    // print the copy to a string stream
    std::stringstream copySS;
    for (int i = 0; i < copyArr.length; i++) {
      copySS << copyArr[i] << " ";
    }
    // compare the copy and the original
    CHECK(originalSS.str() == copySS.str());
  }

  // test the reverse function
  SECTION("Reverse") {
    // call reverse
    nums.reverse();
    // print the reverse to a string stream from back to front
    std::stringstream reverseSS;
    for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      reverseSS << nums[i] << " ";
    }
    // compare the original with the reversed
    CHECK(originalSS.str() == reverseSS.str());
  }
}
```

error message

```
error: request for member 'length' in 'other', which is of non-class type 'int*'
   44 |     length = other.length;
```

Comment: You're trying to use the `.` operator on an `int*` type local type variable. The error tells you as much.

Comment: Where you wrote `int *other;` and then followed it up with `length = other.length;`, what were you expecting `other.length` to mean? How were you expecting it to compute a value?

Comment: Think about where your copy constructor copies the array elements to.

Comment: I find it a bitt confusing that you do things right in one part of the code, but completely wrong in the next part. For example dynamic array allocation is done right in `IntArray(int len)` but in `IntArray(const IntArray &x)` you use a non-standard VLA. Or, you clearly know that `x` is the thing you want to copy, hence you write `x.storedArray`, but for the length you declare a randomg pointer and attempt to read the length from it. And in `arr[i] = x.storedArray[length];` it should be obvious that one index is wrong. So, spend more time reading your own code, you know how to do it right.

Answer (score 2):

In this line of code,

```cpp
int *other;
int arr[length];
length = other.length;
```

`other` is of type `int*`. This is exactly what the error is telling you. Perhaps what your looking for is `x.length`.

And another thing I caught here is that the newly created array size might not be what you need as `length` is uninitialized. So I'm guessing what you meant to do is,

```cpp
length = x.length;
sortedArray = new int[length];    // Since its the copy constructor, you can directly allocate.

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    sortedArray[i] = x.storedArray[i];    // Here x.storedArray should be indexed using 'i'. If not you might be asking for undefined behavior and will not copy data properly.
}
```